# Symfony: How to use resetViewTransformers() in an Event

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I want to use the `resetViewTransformers()`-function on two of my Form fields, but the thing is i am using an EventListener for my builder as you can see here:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($formFactory, $locale) {
    /** @var PollResult $data */
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    $fieldOptions = [];
    $fieldOptions['required'] = false;
    $form->add($formFactory->createNamed('value', 'choice', null, $fieldOptions));
}
```

now i'd like to call `$builder->get('value')->resetViewTransformers();` but when i do that outside the eventi get the error `The child with the name "value" does not exist.`  and inside the variable $builder is unknown.

How can i do that?